# Azure AD assign a role to other organization users

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I have a multitenant application and I registered it in App registration and Enterprise applications.

I want each partner to be able to manage their users.
How can I grant this permission to the partners?

for example, I want the Azure AD admin of Company A, add their user and assign them a "company A" role
then Company B, do the same for their user.

I don't want to add their user by myself. I want to grant access to the Azure Admin of each company to manage their users

Comment: Please edit your question and explain what you mean by `I want each partner to be able to manage their users`?

Comment: Thanks. One more clarification question - These roles "Company A", "Company B" are defined in your app registration. Correct? What work these roles do?

Comment: @GauravMantri No, I want each company to define its roles and assign their user to their roles.
based on the user role, I want to show some articles to a user.

Comment: I'm not sure if it is even possible to have each company define their own application roles and have your application understand them. The roles are defined at the application level (i.e. app registration level) which you would define. Once an organization consents to your application, an enterprise application is created in their tenant. They can then assign your application roles to the users in their Azure AD.

Comment: @GauravMantri So I need to ask their Azure AD admin to login to our application and consent to the app permission.
then their admin can add their user into the predefined roles?

Comment: That’s correct.

Comment: @GauravMantri can I limit their Azure AD admin to be able to just assign specific roles,
for example, I want the Company_A's Azure AD admin just to be able to assign their user to role "Company_A_Article)

Comment: Nope. These roles are application specific roles and not customer specific.